# How to solve Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CheckboxControlValueAccessor -> Renderer2]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to update to ng7 and also to use my custom ng7 library to outsource some code outside my main project.

Here's some strange error that I get:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CheckboxControlValueAccessor -> Renderer2]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CheckboxControlValueAccessor -> Renderer2]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CheckboxControlValueAccessor -> Renderer2]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CheckboxControlValueAccessor -> Renderer2]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2!
>       at NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at zone.js:892
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)

The strange thing is that I don't directly use neither CheckboxControlValueAccessor nor the Renderer2.

Here's my code for app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module";
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import { NgPipesModule } from "ngx-pipes";
import { NgbModal, NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from "angular-highcharts";

import { ScrollToModule } from "ng2-scroll-to-el";
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from "ng-circle-progress";
import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseAppConfig } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from "@angular/fire/storage";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { TCoreModule } from "@eriendel/t-core";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

declare var require: any;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        CoreModule,
        TCoreModule.forRoot(),
        AuthModule.forRoot({
            autoAuthRoleCredentials: environment.autoAuthRoleCredentials
        }),
        FormsModule,
        NgPipesModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NgbModule,
        ChartModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireStorageModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({}),
        ScrollToModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        NgbModal,
        {
            provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES,
            useFactory: () => [require("highcharts/highcharts-more.src")]
        } // add as factory to your providers
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here's the plugin's module code:

```js
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import {
    HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    HttpClient,
    HttpClientModule
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";
import localeUk from "@angular/common/locales/uk";

registerLocaleData(localeUk);

import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { LoggingInterceptor } from "./logging.interceptor";
import { DatesService } from "./dates.service";
import { LocalizationService } from "./localization.service";
import { CalculationsService } from "./calculations/calculations.service";
import { NavService } from "./nav.service";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpLoaderFactory } from "./HttpLoaderFactory";
import { UIModule } from "./ui/ui.module";
import { ButtonAddRowComponent } from "./ui/button-add-row/button-add-row.component";
import { ButtonConfirmComponent } from "./ui/button-confirm/button-confirm.component";
import { CompositeFilterBoxComponent } from "./ui/composite-filter-box/composite-filter-box.component";
import { CompositeRangeDatepickerComponent } from "./ui/composite-range-datepicker/composite-range-datepicker.component";
import { CrudObjectsListComponent } from "./ui/crud-objects-list/crud-objects-list.component";
import { PopupTemplateComponent } from "./ui/popup-template/popup-template.component";
import { RangeDatepickerComponent } from "./ui/range-datepicker/range-datepicker.component";
import { DisableControlDirective } from "./ui/disable-control.directive";
import { SumPropPipe } from "./ui/sumProp.pipe";
import { WithoutObjectPipe } from "./ui/withoutObject.pipe";
import { NotFoundComponent } from "./ui/not-found/not-found.component";

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgbModule,
        UIModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    exports: [
        ButtonAddRowComponent,
        ButtonConfirmComponent,
        CompositeFilterBoxComponent,
        CompositeRangeDatepickerComponent,
        CrudObjectsListComponent,
        PopupTemplateComponent,
        RangeDatepickerComponent,
        DisableControlDirective,
        SumPropPipe,
        WithoutObjectPipe,
        NotFoundComponent
    ]
})
export class TCoreModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: TCoreModule,
            providers: [
                CalculationsService,
                DatesService,
                LocalizationService,
                NavService,
                {
                    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                    useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
                    multi: true
                },
                {
                    provide: LOCALE_ID,
                    deps: [LocalizationService],
                    useFactory: localizationService =>
                        localizationService.getLocale()
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return this.forRoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where is CheckboxControlValueAccessor come from

Comment: @TonyNgo it's defined in forms module that I use in my library, but I don't directly use it in any place of my lib

Comment: What is the library ?

Comment: @TonyNgo it's my private library, I cannot post all the code. But if something else is important to publish, I can do that, just tell me.

Comment: Is really hard to help you. But you have that error because your library are using it some where